# Do While Loop menu in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with this do-while loop menu for a program I'm working on for school. I've checked, and as far as I'm concerned I have written the code correctly. However, when testing, if I type 'y' or 'n' the result is the same: the menu streaming down 100's of times non stop until I exit the program. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong and how I can get it to display the menu properly every time? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "CashRegister.h"
#include "InventoryItem.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Variables
int selection, numUnits, cont;
double price;

// Use the first constructor for the first item
InventoryItem item1;
item1.setCost(5.0);
item1.setDescription("Adjustable Wrench");
item1.setUnits(10);

// Use the second constructor for the second item
InventoryItem item2("Screwdriver");
item2.setCost(3.0);
item2.setUnits(20);

// Use the third constructor for the remaining items
InventoryItem item3("Pliers", 7.0, 35);
InventoryItem item4("Ratchet", 10.0, 10);
InventoryItem item5("Socket Wrench", 15.0, 7);


do
{
    cout << "#\t" << "Item\t\t\t" << "qty on Hand" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1\t" << item1.getDescription() << "\t" << setw(3) << item1.getUnits() << endl;
    cout << "2\t" << item2.getDescription() << "\t\t" << setw(3) << item2.getUnits() << endl;
    cout << "3\t" << item3.getDescription() << "\t\t\t" << setw(3) << item3.getUnits() << endl;
    cout << "4\t" << item4.getDescription() << "\t\t\t" << setw(3) << item4.getUnits() << endl;
    cout << "5\t" << item5.getDescription() << "\t\t" << setw(3) << item5.getUnits() << endl;
    cout << "Which item above is being purchased? ";
    cin >> selection;

    // Validate the selection
    while (selection < 1 || selection > 5)
    {
        cout << "Error, please make a valid item selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
    }

    cout << "How many units? ";
    cin >> numUnits;

    // Validate the quantity of units to make sure it isn't a negative value
    while (numUnits < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error, please enter a valid quantity: ";
        cin >> numUnits;
    }

    // Use a switch statement to figure out which cost to pull
    switch (selection)
    {
    case 1: {price = item1.getCost();
        item1.changeUnits(numUnits); }
        break;
    case 2: {price = item2.getCost();
        item2.changeUnits(numUnits); }
        break;
    case 3: {price = item3.getCost();
        item3.changeUnits(numUnits); }
        break;
    case 4: {price = item4.getCost();
        item4.changeUnits(numUnits); }
        break;
    case 5: {price = item5.getCost();
        item5.changeUnits(numUnits); }
        break;
    }

    // Create a CashRegister object for this particular selection
    CashRegister transaction(price, numUnits);

    // Display the totals
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Subtotal: $" << transaction.getSubtotal() << endl;
    cout << "Sales Tax: $" << transaction.getSalesTax() << endl;
    cout << "Total: $" << transaction.getPurchaseTotal() << endl;

    // Find out if the user wants to purchase another item
    cout << "Do you want to purchase another item? Enter y/n: ";
    cin >> cont;

} while (cont != 'n' && cont != 'N');

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You declared `cont` as an `int` but then checking if it is `!= 'n'` or `'N'` which are `char`s?

Comment: Should prob change your cont to a char as @FirstStep pointed out

Comment: I don't see where you would want to enter a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will never `break` unless you explicitly enter `110` which is the 'n' char in [**ASCII Codes**](http://www.asciitable.com/) or 78 which is the 'N'. So change your `cont` declaration from `int cont;` to `char cont;` and then you won't get the infinite loop anymore, and its condition will be valid to *possibly* `break` by then unless you have another hidden logical error which will require you to debug it.

Comment: Well, actually, `getchar()` (or `std::cin.get()`) would return an int.

Comment: @Bob__ actually it did. I just tested it. Good catch and thanks

Comment: Glad we were able to help :)